# How to set input direction in react-hook-form?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm building a website that uses **"RTL (Right To Left) language"**, so I implemented **react-hook-form**, but react hook form uses only **"LTR"** forms like so...[image]

In here I'm using the HTML attribute **(dir="RTL")** in my page, so all the text is "RTL" except the **react hook form** how can I fix this?.
[image: this another image to show the problem]

```js
import { TextField, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useFormContext, Controller } from "react-hook-form";


const FormInput = ({ name, label }) => {
    const { control } = useFormContext();
    return (
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <Controller 
                as={TextField} control={control} fullWidth name={name} label={label} required defaultValue=""/>
        </Grid>
    )
}

export default FormInput;
```

this is **my FormInput component**, I export this component to my **address form component**

```js
import { useForm, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form";


<FormProvider>
    <form>
            <FormInput name="firstName" label="الإسم الأول (first name)" />
            <FormInput name="lastName" label="اسم العائلة (last name)" />    
    </form>
</FormProvider>
```

this is my **address form component**.

Comment: use css - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction. It looks like you are using material core - https://material.io/design/usability/bidirectionality.html#mirroring-layout

Comment: @Sean I tried to put it in the chrome developer tool on one of the react hook form input div but it didn't work.

Comment: React hook form does not control the direction of your forms - you do.  Your problem is likely in the FormInput component (or could be CSS).  You need to post the FormInput component to allow someone to help you.